# Helpful flag text box is trying to escape from the popup in the new beta design

Tags: bug, flags, design, moderator-tools

With the new beta design, the helpful flag reason textbox on flags doesn't have enough padding to the right:

[image]

Compare with the decline box:

[image]

Could we make the helpful box less cramped?

Comment: A thing to mention here is that this [has happened before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284219/flags-other-box-is-too-large-comment-flagging), only with the comment flag's 'other' box.